# White background when moving between carousel slides

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with my html website. I am currently using Bootstrap-5. When I change the slides using carousel in website, there is white blanks keep appearing. How can I deal with this problem?

Here is my code!

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="kr">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>P&P</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">P & P</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Some Script
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some script</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some script</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some script</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>  
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active"href="#">Some script</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some script</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some script</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


 
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="lemon_wp.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Some script<br>Some script</h5>
          <h6><br>Some script</h6>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="lemon_wp.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Some script<br></h5>
          <h6>Some script<br>Other script</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

    </a>
  </div>
  
  <section class="babies">
      <div class="container py-5">
          <div class="row py-5">
              <class class="col-lg-5">
                  <h1></h1>
              </class>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: black;
}
.navbar-brand:hober{
    color: black;
}
.nav-link{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color: black;
}
.main{
    background-color: lemonchiffon;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.main h1{
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    /*fontfamiliy*/
}
.absolute-div {
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
}
.item {
    position:relative;
}
.carousel-item{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat scroll center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.carousel-item::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.carousel-caption{
    bottom: 35%;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.carousel-caption h5{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.carousel-caption h6{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon:after{
   content: '>';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
 }
  
.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
   content: '<';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
 }
.carousel {
    width:100% !important; 
    overflow: hidden !important; 
    right:0 !important; 
}
.carousel-inner{
    overflow:visible
}
```

I cannot really find the problem in my code.
The carousel example that I use is from the bootstrap official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening but you can try this it works on your code

```
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="a.lpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Some script<br>Some script</h5>
          <h6><br>Some script</h6>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="b.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Some script<br>Some script</h5>
          <h6><br>Some script</h6>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="c.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Some script<br>Some script</h5>
          <h6><br>Some script</h6>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

and you don't need this code on your css you have it by default in bootstrap

```
.carousel-control-next-icon:after{
   content: '>';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
 }
  
.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
   content: '<';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

dear when you add carousel slider it auto append white arrow for slider movement to left right its part of carousel default css and in your css you had also added the arrow by the code given below

```
.carousel-control-next-icon:after{
   content: '>';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
 }

.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
   content: '<';
   font-size: 55px;
   color: black;
}
```

try to comment it so it will remove the black arrow
or use carousal javacript method to remove the black arrow